# Is it possible to force method overload based on an enum in typescript?

Tags: typescript

This is probably a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67098183/typescript-how-to-overload-a-function-of-an-interface-in-another-interface-that/67098332#67098332). I have an enum

```js
export enum RewardAdPluginEvents {
  Loaded= 'onRewardedVideoAdLoaded',
  FailedToLoad= 'onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad',
  Showed= 'onRewardedVideoAdShowed',
  FailedToShow= 'onRewardedVideoAdFailedToShow',
  Dismissed= 'onRewardedVideoAdDismissed',
  Rewarded= 'onRewardedVideoAdReward',
}
```

An I have an interface that needs overloads like this:

```js
  addListener(
    eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.Dismissed,
    listenerFunc: () => void,
  ): PluginListenerHandle;

  addListener(
    eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.FailedToLoad,
    listenerFunc: (error: ErrorInfo) => void,
  ): PluginListenerHandle;
  
  addListener(
    eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.Rewarded,
    listenerFunc: (item: RewardItem) => void,
  ) : PluginListenerHandle;
```

Is there a way to force the interface to implement all that overloads?

I tried with

```js
import type { PluginListenerHandle } from '@capacitor/core';

type Enum<E> = Record<keyof E, string> & { [k: string]: string };

export type HasListeners<Enum> = { addListener: (eventName: keyof Enum, listenerFunc: (info: any) => void) => PluginListenerHandle }
```

and then

```js
export interface RewardDefinitions extends HasListeners<RewardAdPluginEvents>{
```

but it fails because it takes too many keys that come from an object:

> Interface 'RewardDefinitions' incorrectly extends interface 'HasListeners'.
> Types of property 'addListener' are incompatible.
> Type '{ (eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.Dismissed, listenerFunc: () => void): PluginListenerHandle; (eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.FailedToLoad, listenerFunc: () => void): PluginListenerHandle; (eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.FailedToShow, listenerFunc: () => void): PluginListenerHandle; (eventName: RewardAdPluginEven...' is not assignable to type '(eventName: number | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | "toLowerCase" | ... 31 more ... | "trimEnd", listenerFunc: (info: any) => void) => PluginListenerHandle'.
> Types of parameters 'eventName' and 'eventName' are incompatible.
> Type 'number | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | "toLowerCase" | ... 31 more ... | "trimEnd"' is not assignable to type 'RewardAdPluginEvents.Dismissed'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'RewardAdPluginEvents.Dismissed'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but not terribly straightforward. Overloads are intersections of functions, which are trickier to manipulate than unions.

First you'll need something to turn a union into an intersection, which can be done  with inference on a contravariant parameter in a conditional type ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)). This is a bit techical, so I'll omit the full explanation here.

```
type Contra<T> = (x: T) => void
type UnwrapContra<T> = [T] extends [Contra<infer S>] ? S : never
type UnionToIntersection<U> = UnwrapContra<U extends any ? Contra<U> : never>
```

For example, `UnionToIntersection<{a:1}|{b:2}>` evaluates to `{a:1} & {b:2}`. Now you'll need to get a union of all overloads, which is a bit more straightforward. Just declare a type `Overload` that creates a single overload, and use a conditional type to distribute it over each member of the enum.

```
type Overload<T> =
  (eventName: T, listenerFunc: (...args: any[]) => any) => PluginListenerHandle
type OverloadUnionForEnum<T> = T extends any ? Overload<T> : never

type OverloadUnion = OverloadUnionForEnum<RewardAdPluginEvents>
```

The resulting `OverloadUnion` a union of overloads, one for each member of `RewardAdPluginEvents`: `Overload<RewardAdPluginEvents.FailedToLoad> | Overload<RewardAdPluginEvents.Dismissed> | ..`

Turning this union into an intersection yields the actual overloaded function signature for `addListener`:

```
type Overloads = UnionToIntersection<OverloadUnion>
```

With all that out of the way, you can now define a type `Validate` that constrains its argument to have an `addListener` property that conforms to the overloads:

```
type Validate<T extends {addListener: Overloads}> = T
```

To use `Validate`, consider two interfaces `ListenerA` and `ListenerB` that both contain some of the overloads, and restrict `RewardAdPluginEvents` to just `Dismissed`, `FailedToLoad`, and `Rewarded` for now to keep the types a bit smaller:

```
interface ListenerA {
  addListener(
    eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.Dismissed,
    listenerFunc: () => void,
  ): PluginListenerHandle;
}

interface ListenerB {
  addListener(
    eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.FailedToLoad,
    listenerFunc: (error: ErrorInfo) => void,
  ): PluginListenerHandle;
  addListener(
    eventName: RewardAdPluginEvents.Rewarded,
    listenerFunc: (item: RewardItem) => void,
  ) : PluginListenerHandle;
}
```

Validating either `ListenerA` or `ListenerB` fails as it should, with a large error message that has a somewhat readable last line:

```
type Invalid1 = Validate<ListenerA>
// ERROR: ... Type 'RewardAdPluginEvents.FailedToLoad' is not assignable to
//        type 'RewardAdPluginEvents.Dismissed'.
type Invalid2 = Validate<ListenerB> 
// ERROR: ... Type 'RewardAdPluginEvents.Dismissed' is not assignable to
//        type 'RewardAdPluginEvents.FailedToLoad'.
```

When the two are combine, all overloads are present and, validation passes:

```
export type Combined = Validate<ListenerA & ListenerB> // No error!
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgVwOYEsB2AZFBnYE0QBOAEgIZoAmc0AvFAN4C+AsAFCiRQCihhA9oQCSaAGZ8odJmw7QAShADupQhUF4AthIYtWbfAk3ylKgIIV4ydFwBu+YNgZsoUAPQuoAYT7r1diBShSKBFFKABrCBAHYHEIiDAoYAALaBkHQghSClIAI2onV3cMPiz-OgByPjQjZQp-ADUUOr4zYtKKcoAaArcoAGUkvgUyqErqxVqGpogWigGh-y6e9wAxUhRqCgAVPnmFCqqalSnmszWN-x29pdZnc82dtooD8eM6ikbTinvLvieb5wAERw6hw2BGYyO70+MzMwOwoOw4I63VuUChEMOE2OH2msyhNx00nA0C8aGAhFIAB4tgA+LQACgAHgAuKBbACUEnp1j4TWJnAAqmgFJSwGSKdS6VoANpbAC6UAgTLwlAcMollKp6BChH6tMVAH5+lA2QRbIQBdBhSgqjthHhCOCAMbAW1oKmC+l0YWi0jiqqSz1KlX4CgOcggKDGzXUr2mqDmoi0q3siC4G12vgOogut1VLSZtD28m5iCu91U+ikFkARkYAB96DkWQAmRj03oyNnVuuMABkzbbRPYJKgAHkLXAShQad6ClAGRBbOSAHKkXxsradKBwHCqogrBBoZ1shkAOkvyiQ2DZkZl8q5NHpkaf9IsqEw+-wRDIlHyo6cJORDTlkRYrAIXBoAYc5aFsIaquGgRoFGxrAYQoGztKZrLkQbCpuhmFFlohEzuBkHQeoVJQmYH5WCu9gpqwvQTlOM7UdiFC0Ygn42HY2Dnj82x-DO9INqxIHsTR5g8fR-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-L2CK8reSpOr-OC6VOtHeLBuRcqYACHLNNeOoOToP45us+z53JVA-YzVntuFFAq7iDdAgAIRAA)

Comment: Thank you @oblosys, I have to test it later because the Playground link does not work :)

Comment: @distante Always forget to add tags to answer comments.